# Struggling to figure out how to use UserDefault to keep the user logged in

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, nsuserdefaults, mac-catalyst

I keep struggling to implement UserDefaults in my iOS app. I have looked through other answers but it isn't clear to me whether I do it in the `AppDelegate`, `viewDidAppear`, or somewhere else. This is what I have tried so far.

In my login function:

```
 // If auth success, let through to next VC
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: loginEmail.text!, password: loginPassword.text!) { (authData, err) in
            
            if (err != nil) {
                let rootVC = HomeVC()
                
                let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootVC)
                navVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                navVC.isNavigationBarHidden = true
                
                UserDefaults.standard.set(FirebaseAuth.Auth.auth().currentUser, forKey: "user_id_key")
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                
                
                self.present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                
            } else {
                
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Authentication Failed.", message: "Please try again.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                
            }
            
        }
```

In my sign up function:

```
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTxtField.text!, password: passwordTxtField.text!) { (authData, err) in
            if (err != nil) {
                let rootVC = HomeVC()
                
                let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootVC)
                navVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                navVC.isNavigationBarHidden = true
                
                UserDefaults.standard.set(FirebaseAuth.Auth.auth().currentUser, forKey: "user_id_key")
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                
                
                self.present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                
            } else {
                
                if self.passwordTxtField.text!.count < 6 {
                    
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Password too short", message: "Password must be at least 6 characters long.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    
                } else {
                    
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Authentication Failed", message: "Please check your email and password", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    
                }
                
                
                
            }
```

The UserDefault isn't working and I keep having to re-log the user back in. I am using Firebase for managing user authentication. I'd appreciate any sort of help if possible!

Answer (score 1):

Firebase automatically restores the user authentication state on app startup. But since this requires a call to the server (to check amongst others whether the account was disabled), this happens asynchronously and may not be done by the time your code check `FirebaseAuth.Auth.auth().currentUser`.

The only reliable way to detect user authentication state in such situations is with an auth state listener as shown in the first snippet in the documentation on [getting the currently signed in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

```
handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
  // ...
}
```

This `// ...` block will automatically be called when the auth state changes (so it the user is signed in or out), so is the perfect place to put code that needs to run when the auth state changes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am a bit of a beginner to this. But if I use this function, will I no longer have to use UserDefault? and do I add this to my sign up/login Firebase functions?

Comment: If you were using `UserDefault` to persist the user authentication state, then that is indeed not needed with Firebase. I typically add this code somewhere that runs on initialization of the view.